# 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' swift 3

Tags: json, swift, error-handling

The following line of code:

```
let jsonData = JSON(data: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)
```

causing the following error:

[image]

Comment: It seems like two frameworks have the same type named `JSON`. I think you're using `SwiftyJSON`, try specifying it: `let jsonData = SwiftyJSON.JSON([...])`

Comment: I doubt that any API has an `error` parameter in Swift 3. And why are you assigning an object with `.mutableContainers` to an immutable constant?

Comment: are you using `do {} catch {}` with `try`?

Answer (score 0):

The best in swift 3 using **SwiftyJSON**

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON

after that :-

```
import SwiftyJSON
```

this code:-

```
let json = JSON(data)
let results = json["animals"].array
```

Answer (score -2):

The parameter `options` is an array.

`let jsonData = JSON(data: data, options: [JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers], error: nil)`

Comment: The parameter `options` is an **option set** and should be completely omitted in this case (and is not the reason of the issue).